# What is the impact if I mandate all PL/SQL packages to NOT have an EXIT statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In a particular product, we have many `packages` in a particular installation. We have checked even if we remove `Exit` statement, our processing becomes faster. and it does not make any changes in our flow. what is impact of the exit statement in package?

```
/
COMMIT;
EXIT; <------ We want to remove this
```

Comment: is the `exit` inside a PL/SQL procedure/function/package, or is it in a script that is run via, e.g. SQL*Plus?

Comment: It is inside the package.

Comment: No, it is not, Onkar. Can't be, unless it is within a loop.

Comment: I need to check client code...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this `EXIT` certainly isn't part of those *packages* as it is only used to exit a loop:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test is
  3      begin
  4        null;
  5        exit;          --> exit is here
  6    end;
  7  end;
  8  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/7      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/7      PLS-00376: illegal EXIT/CONTINUE statement; it must appear inside
         a loop

SQL>
```

As a SQL*Plus command, `EXIT` (from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve023.htm#SQPUG044))

> commits or rolls back all pending changes, logs out of Oracle Database, terminates SQL*Plus and returns control to the operating system.

I presume you use it at the end of your .SQL scripts that create database objects (at least, that's how I understood "in a particular **installation**" you mentioned).

If that's so, you see what it does. If you omit it, once the processing reaches the end of the .SQL script, it will stay in SQL*Plus and won't exit it so you'll have to do it manually.

Finally, `create package` and similar commands are DDL and they implicitly commit, so - your `commit` at the end of the script is pretty much useless (unless there's some DML that we don't see).